# Number to Percentage of column datatype Varchar

Tags: sql-server

I want to display number as percentage as shown below, The column  datatype is Varchar

```
1       100.0% 
0.8      80.0% 
0.9      90.0%
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show us your effort and let us sort out your specific problem.

Comment: The next step is to write some code and after that if you run in to any issue then come here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48227971/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see **[ask]**.

Comment: Rather than doing this in SQL Server, do it in your presentation layer. Also, why are you storing decimals as a `varchar`? Store them in an appropriate data type (such as `decimal(4,2)`).

Comment: If 2012+ try   Select format(0.8,'0.0%')    returns 80.0% ... CAUTION: performance may suffer.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

- create a CTE
- convert it to a numeric data type like decimal
- multiply the value by 100
- convert the value back to varchar and tack on the percentage sign

  ```
  with tab as
  ( Select (cast(column1 as decimal(9,1)) *100) as 'newcolumn'
  From sample1)

  Select cast(newcolumn as varchar(12)) + '%' as 'Percent'
  From tab
  ```

Original Data:

```
Select * from sample1
column1
1
0.5
0.2
```

Output:

```
Percent
100.0%
50.0%
20.0%
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
DECLARE @numberdata AS TABLE ( Number VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @numberdata
SELECT 1   UNION ALL     
SELECT 0.8 UNION ALL    
SELECT 0.9

SELECT * FROM @numberdata
```

We should not save numerical data in string format , if you want get data in the form percentage first cast the number column data from varchar to decimal data type and multiply with 100. Try this below

```
SELECT  Number,
CAST(CAST(Number AS DECIMAL(4,1))*100 AS VARCHAR(10))+'%' AS InPercantage FROM @numberdata
```

Result

```
Number  InPercantage
--------------------
1.0      100.0%
0.8      80.0%
0.9      90.0%
```